# Custom Repeat not breaking in IF

Tags: opentap-proj

I am creating a CustomRepeat by extending CustomLoopTest. It never breaks in the IF condition.

Because break happens only for concrete class LoopTestStep, is it possible to modify LoopTestStep inside the IF condition by an interface? So we can implement that interface in our CustomLoopTestStep.

Another possiblity is to help to provide an alternative way.

```
public abstract class CustomLoopTestStep : CustomTestStep
    {
        protected CancellationTokenSource breakLoopToken { get; private set; }

        [Browsable(false)]
        protected CancellationToken BreakLoopRequested { get { return breakLoopToken.Token; } }

        public CustomLoopTestStep()
        {
            breakLoopToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        public void BreakLoop()
        {
            breakLoopToken.Cancel();
        }

        /// <summary> Always call base.Run in LoopTestStep inheritors. </summary>
        public override void Run()
        {
            breakLoopToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (OpenTAP v9.4 and earlier), you need to inherit from `LoopTestStep` to interact with the If Verdict step. Otherwise if you prefer to achieve this by implementing an interface, you can submit a feature request [here](https://gitlab.com/OpenTAP/opentap/issues/new?issue%5Bassignee_id%5D=&issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=) to add an interface in OpenTAP.